# Can you identify the set from these two LEGO bags?

Tags: set-identification

Can someone please help identify this LEGO set? I’m not certain the 2 bags go together.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Left Plate W. Angle 3X12](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6054536) only comes in Bright Red in 6 sets. Only 1 set also contains this piece in White.

[31047-1: Propeller Plane](https://brickset.com/sets/31047-1/Propeller-Plane)

[image]

This set also contains:

- [403224: Plate 2X2 Round](https://brickset.com/parts/403224/plate-2x2-round) in Bright Yellow
- [4560179: Flat Tile 2X4](https://brickset.com/parts/4560179/flat-tile-2x4) in Bright Red
- [4211440: Technic Brick 1X2, Ø4.9](https://brickset.com/parts/4211440/technic-brick-1x2-%C3%B84-9)  in Medium Stone Grey
- [6083620: Cross Axle 4M With End Stop](https://brickset.com/parts/6083620/cross-axle-4m-with-end-stop) in Dark Stone Grey

So both bags are from the same set.